# How to prevent rectangles in a SSRS from merging/growing?

Tags: reporting-services, rectangles

The rectangles on my SSRS reports keep on merging/growing in size. I searched a bit, but nothing seems to fit my current situation.

Let's say rectangle 1 is 2x5. When I add rectangle 2, which is also 2x5, and I click on rectangle 1, both rectangle 1 and 2 are highlighted and it says rectangle 1's size is 4x5. I have included and image below.

```
+------------------------------+
|   +----------------------+   |
|   |                      |   |
|   |          1           |   |
|   |                      |   |
|   +----------------------+   |
|   |                      |   |
|   |          2           |   |
|   |                      |   |
|   +----------------------+   |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
+------------------------------+
```

I can't seem to alter the size of rectangle 1. It just grew/merged with rectangle 2 <-- Rectangle 2 parent changes from Body to rectangle 1 when I move rectangle 2 up to rectangle 1, where there no gap in between.

Anyone have any idea? I am doing this using VS Premium 2012 with SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

Is rectangle2 going INSIDE rectangle1?  Use the Document Outline Window (View menu -> Other Windows) to see what controls are inside other controls.

Comment: ask questions in comments & not in answer section.